# Showing a table within a table on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table

I created a table within a table but I would like to only show the second table upon click like an accordion. I tried to implement the code I found here:    `http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/6Texj/` but could not replicated the results. Can anyone help?

Here is the html:

```
<body ng-controller="basicCtrl">
<h1 style="text-align: center">Michael Z Wang</h1>
<table st-table="jobCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort="company" st-skip-natural="true">Company</th>
            <th st-sort="location" st-skip-natural="true">Location</th>
            <th st-sort="postion" st-skip-natural="true">Position Held</th>
            <th st-sort="startDate" st-sort-default="reverse" st-skip-natural="true">Start Date</th>
            <th st-sort="endDate" st-skip-natural="true">End Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="job in jobCollection">
        <tr id="jobDetails" class="clickableRow" ng-click="openDetail($index)">
            <td>{{job.company}}</td>
            <td>{{job.location}}</td>
            <td>{{job.position}}</td>
            <td>{{job.startDate | date : 'MM/yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{job.stopDate | date : 'MM/yyyy'}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1"></td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <div collapse="jobCollapsed[$index]">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Job Details</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="detail in jobCollection[$index].jobDetails">
                            <tr><td>{{detail.detail1}}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{detail.detail2}}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{detail.detail3}}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{detail.detail4}}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>{{detail.detail5}}</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table'])
myApp.controller('basicCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter',
function ($scope) {
    $scope.tableRowExpanded = false;
    $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded = "";
    $scope.tableRowIndexPrevExpanded = "";
    $scope.jobCollapsed = [true, true, true, true, true, true]

    $scope.openDetail = function (index) {
        if ($scope.tableRowExpanded === false && $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded === "") {
            $scope.tableRowIndexPrevExpanded = "";
            $scope.tableRowExpanded = true;
            $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded = index;
            $scope.jobCollapsed[index] = false;
        } else if ($scope.tableRowExpanded === true) {
            if ($scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded === index) {
                $scope.tableRowExpanded = false;
                $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded = "";
                $scope.jobCollapsed[index] = true;
            } else {
                $scope.tableRowIndexPrevExpanded = $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded;
                $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded = index;
                $scope.jobCollapsed[$scope.tableRowIndexPrevExpanded] = true;
                $scope.jobCollapsed[$scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded] = false;
            }
        }
    };

            $scope.jobCollection = [
                {
                    company: 'Dell',
                    location: 'Madison, WI',
                    position: 'Software Development Advisor',
                    startDate: new Date('2015/06'),
                    stopDate: new Date('2015/08'),
                    jobDetails: [{
                        detail1: 'Created a light-weight, portable product that stores logs accessible from a web or mobile browser',
                        detail2: 'Created an appender to synchronously transfer logs to above product',
                        detail3: 'Learned many new technologies in a short amount of time to develop product.',
                        detail4: 'Used AGILE programming techniques'
                    }]
                },
                {
                    company: 'Blue Harbor Resort',
                    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
                    position: 'IT Assistant',
                    startDate: new Date('2015/02'),
                    stopDate: new Date('2015/05')
                },
                {
                    company: 'Lakeland College',
                    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
                    position: 'IT Helpdesk',
                    startDate: new Date('2015/01'),
                    stopDate: new Date('2015/05')
                },
                {
                    company: 'Kleen Test Products',
                    location: 'Port Washington, WI',
                    position: 'Quality Technician',
                    startDate: new Date('2013/07'),
                    stopDate: new Date('2015/01')
                },
                {
                    company: 'Rockline',
                    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
                    position: 'Quality Assurance Analyst',
                    startDate: new Date('2013/01'),
                    stopDate: new Date('2013/05')
                },
                {
                    company: 'Orion Energy Systems',
                    location: 'Plymouth, WI',
                    position: 'Engineering Aide',
                    startDate: new Date('2011/05'),
                    stopDate: new Date('2011/09')
                }
            ];

            $scope.status = {
                open: true
            }
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` to decide whether to create the details element or not, also use an array like `showDetails` to store the opened state for each item.

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('basicCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showDetails = []

  $scope.openDetail = function(index) {
    $scope.showDetails[index] = !$scope.showDetails[index];
  };

  $scope.jobCollection = [{
    company: 'Dell',
    location: 'Madison, WI',
    position: 'Software Development Advisor',
    startDate: new Date('2015/06'),
    stopDate: new Date('2015/08'),
    jobDetails: [{
      detail1: 'Created a light-weight, portable product that stores logs accessible from a web or mobile browser',
      detail2: 'Created an appender to synchronously transfer logs to above product',
      detail3: 'Learned many new technologies in a short amount of time to develop product.',
      detail4: 'Used AGILE programming techniques'
    }]
  }, {
    company: 'Blue Harbor Resort',
    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
    position: 'IT Assistant',
    startDate: new Date('2015/02'),
    stopDate: new Date('2015/05')
  }, {
    company: 'Lakeland College',
    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
    position: 'IT Helpdesk',
    startDate: new Date('2015/01'),
    stopDate: new Date('2015/05'),
    jobDetails: [{
      detail1: 'Created a light-weight, portable product that stores logs accessible from a web or mobile browser',
      detail2: 'Created an appender to synchronously transfer logs to above product',
      detail3: 'Learned many new technologies in a short amount of time to develop product.',
      detail4: 'Used AGILE programming techniques'
    }]
  }, {
    company: 'Kleen Test Products',
    location: 'Port Washington, WI',
    position: 'Quality Technician',
    startDate: new Date('2013/07'),
    stopDate: new Date('2015/01')
  }, {
    company: 'Rockline',
    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
    position: 'Quality Assurance Analyst',
    startDate: new Date('2013/01'),
    stopDate: new Date('2013/05')
  }, {
    company: 'Orion Energy Systems',
    location: 'Plymouth, WI',
    position: 'Engineering Aide',
    startDate: new Date('2011/05'),
    stopDate: new Date('2011/09')
  }];

  $scope.status = {
    open: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">

<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="basicCtrl">
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Michael Z Wang</h1>

  <table st-table="jobCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th st-sort="company" st-skip-natural="true">Company</th>
        <th st-sort="location" st-skip-natural="true">Location</th>
        <th st-sort="postion" st-skip-natural="true">Position Held</th>
        <th st-sort="startDate" st-sort-default="reverse" st-skip-natural="true">Start Date</th>
        <th st-sort="endDate" st-skip-natural="true">End Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="job in jobCollection">
      <tr id="jobDetails" class="clickableRow" ng-click="openDetail($index)">
        <td>{{job.company}}</td>
        <td>{{job.location}}</td>
        <td>{{job.position}}</td>
        <td>{{job.startDate | date : 'MM/yyyy'}}</td>
        <td>{{job.stopDate | date : 'MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="job.jobDetails.length" ng-show="showDetails[$index]">
        <td colspan="1"></td>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div collapse="jobCollapsed[$index]">
            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Job Details</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody ng-repeat="detail in job.jobDetails">
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail1}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail2}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail3}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail4}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail5}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

You can also store the opened state in the `job` object itself like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('basicCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.jobCollection = [{
    company: 'Dell',
    location: 'Madison, WI',
    position: 'Software Development Advisor',
    startDate: new Date('2015/06'),
    stopDate: new Date('2015/08'),
    jobDetails: [{
      detail1: 'Created a light-weight, portable product that stores logs accessible from a web or mobile browser',
      detail2: 'Created an appender to synchronously transfer logs to above product',
      detail3: 'Learned many new technologies in a short amount of time to develop product.',
      detail4: 'Used AGILE programming techniques'
    }]
  }, {
    company: 'Blue Harbor Resort',
    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
    position: 'IT Assistant',
    startDate: new Date('2015/02'),
    stopDate: new Date('2015/05')
  }, {
    company: 'Lakeland College',
    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
    position: 'IT Helpdesk',
    startDate: new Date('2015/01'),
    stopDate: new Date('2015/05'),
    jobDetails: [{
      detail1: 'Created a light-weight, portable product that stores logs accessible from a web or mobile browser',
      detail2: 'Created an appender to synchronously transfer logs to above product',
      detail3: 'Learned many new technologies in a short amount of time to develop product.',
      detail4: 'Used AGILE programming techniques'
    }]
  }, {
    company: 'Kleen Test Products',
    location: 'Port Washington, WI',
    position: 'Quality Technician',
    startDate: new Date('2013/07'),
    stopDate: new Date('2015/01')
  }, {
    company: 'Rockline',
    location: 'Sheboygan, WI',
    position: 'Quality Assurance Analyst',
    startDate: new Date('2013/01'),
    stopDate: new Date('2013/05')
  }, {
    company: 'Orion Energy Systems',
    location: 'Plymouth, WI',
    position: 'Engineering Aide',
    startDate: new Date('2011/05'),
    stopDate: new Date('2011/09')
  }];

  $scope.status = {
    open: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">

<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="basicCtrl">
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Michael Z Wang</h1>

  <table st-table="jobCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th st-sort="company" st-skip-natural="true">Company</th>
        <th st-sort="location" st-skip-natural="true">Location</th>
        <th st-sort="postion" st-skip-natural="true">Position Held</th>
        <th st-sort="startDate" st-sort-default="reverse" st-skip-natural="true">Start Date</th>
        <th st-sort="endDate" st-skip-natural="true">End Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="job in jobCollection">
      <tr id="jobDetails" class="clickableRow" ng-click="job.opened = !job.opened">
        <td>{{job.company}}</td>
        <td>{{job.location}}</td>
        <td>{{job.position}}</td>
        <td>{{job.startDate | date : 'MM/yyyy'}}</td>
        <td>{{job.stopDate | date : 'MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="job.jobDetails.length" ng-show="job.opened">
        <td colspan="1"></td>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div collapse="jobCollapsed[$index]">
            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Job Details</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody ng-repeat="detail in job.jobDetails">
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail1}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail2}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail3}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail4}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{detail.detail5}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```